# Javascript:update result value after input update

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with my script update values.for example:
-I have 2 textfields where i store datetime values 
-one

My problem is that when i change the value in a textbox the final price not updated.
I want when value change in any textfield to auto update the price result

Thanks,

My test Code is :

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         $('#frompicker').datetimepicker();
         $('#topicker').datetimepicker();
     });
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function calculateTime() {
            //get values
            var parkingType = $("select[name='selectParking']").val();
            var valuestart = $("#frompicker").val();
            var valuestop = $("#topicker").val();


            //alert(valuestart);
            var timeStart = new Date(valuestart);
            var timeEnd = new Date(valuestop);

            var hourDiff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 3600000;

            //alert(timeStart);


            if (parkingType == "2" || parkingType == "3") {
             if (hourDiff < 0 ) {
                $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "error" + "€");
            }

            else if (hourDiff >= 1 && hourDiff < 2) {
                $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "2" + "€");
            }
```

} }

```
        $("select").change(calculateTime);
        calculateTime();
    });
```

Comment: Follow this guideline: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the markup, but the javascript looks correct. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7t5u/1/) seems to work.

Markup:

```
<select id="parkingType" name="selectParking">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input id="frompicker" type="text"/>
<input id="topicker" type="text"/>

<p id="output"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#frompicker').datetimepicker();
    $('#topicker').datetimepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    function calculateTime() {
        //get values
        var parkingType = $("select[name='selectParking']").val();
        var valuestart = $("#frompicker").val();
        var valuestop = $("#topicker").val();
        var timeStart = new Date(valuestart);
        var timeEnd = new Date(valuestop);
        var hourDiff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 3600000;

        if (parkingType == "2" || parkingType == "3") {
            if (hourDiff < 0 ) {
                $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "error" + "€");
            } else if (hourDiff >= 1 && hourDiff < 2) {
                $("p").html("<b>price:</b> " + "2" + "€");
            }
        }
    }

    $("select").change(calculateTime);
    calculateTime();
});
```